# Pandoc identifiers for lists

Tags: pandoc

I know you can add some inline identifiers in pandoc, e.g. [Pandoc inline .class and .id elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748781/pandoc-inline-class-and-id-elements) but is this possible for block elements like lists? What is the syntax to add a class to an ordered list, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, [not all pandoc elements accept attributes](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/684). List isn't one of them. However, you can wrap your list in a [Div](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans), which accepts attributes:

```
::: {.class #id key=val}
- my list
- items
:::
```

Comment: Thanks... sorry it took so long to mark this. Just as a note, it seems like this was introduced in pandoc 2.